# Why does a charged particle experience lorentz force while moving in a uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, relativity, relative-motion

Firstly, when a charged particle moves in an infinite uniform linear magnetic field, it experiences a force.But,how does the charge or how do we differentiate that the relative  position of charge is changing with respect to the magnetic field or it's stationary.Field around the charge is B and after a small time interval dt when it has moved a distance dx there is no change in it's position relative to the field field around it is still B.
It's as if it was stationary with respect to the field.

And secondly, consider a hypothetical source capable of producing uniform linear magnetic field over a small region infinitely large with respect to the size of the charge kept in this field.
Will the charge again experience a force if we move this source relative to the charge with some non zero velocity?

Comment: Re your first paragraph: do you have the same question about a charge in a uniform $electric$ field? Does the fact that the field around the charge 'looks' the same if the charge changes position make it seem to you as if it shouldn't be experiencing a force?

Comment: Electric field doesn't need for a charge to be in motion to show effect

Comment: No indeed, but I don't see that this would stop you applying your "no change in surroundings" argument to a charge in an electric field.